# When I convert PNG images from 140x140 to 100x100, the image quality suffers

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, png, thumbnails, imagemagick-convert

When I convert PNG image from 140x140 to 100x100, the image quality suffers.

I have tried this command

> convert "image.png"  -thumbnail 100x100  -quality 100 "out.png"

Comment: PNG quality is does not use the same scale as for JPG in the range of 0 to 100 where 0 is most compressed and 100 and least compressed. But -quality is not the issue.  It is the resampling method used to combine some pixels into a smaller number of pixels. One has to sample the neighborhood and combine pixels. This blending of pixels causes more "blurring" You may want to investigate using -filter xxx with -thumbnail with a different filter to what is being used by default. You will end up trading sharpness for other artifacts. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/

Comment: Try -filter catrom.  Does that make it better?  You can also do -unsharp after -thumbnail to sharpen the results some.